# Recreate "Jeeliz Glasses Studio 3D" in Blender

Tags: materials, webgl

Models exported from Blender lose Roughness, Metalness, and Fresnel or any reflective property when imported to [Jeeliz Glasses Studio 3D](https://jeeliz.com/glassesStudio3D/). The [Document](https://jeeliz.com/glassesStudio3D/doc/GlassesStudio3DDoc.pdf) mentions that some properties may be lost in the process, but it also says that the exports from blender most work quite well.

I think that's because of the lack of a BSDF principled shader in blender back when Jeeliz was released.

Can the Shader nodes in Blender be recreated in an order to work properly when exported to Jeeliz? without a need to tune the material sliders?

Comment: Have you checked the mesh of your model? I've just tried a shiny red metal default cube. It worked in the Jeeliz Glasses Studio 3D without a problem.

Comment: Yes, the models, Metalness value, and roughness value all work fine in Glasses Studio 3D, but Fresnel and Transmission are always off. I'm looking for a solution for those properties as well